# 2011 Jeep Patriot CRD 2.2 - engine does not start // P0685 error

Tags: diesel, starter, jeep, no-crank-no-start, patriot

I have a 2011 Jeep Patriot CRD 2.2 (Euro-Model) that does not start anymore. First boot-up and preheating is normal but when I turn the key further for ignition nothing happens, no sound no movement, nothing.

No Engine Error lights etc. but I still did an OBD-II reading and got a P0685 which I cleared and which did not come back so far during my five attempts to start it.

The battery seems to have enough power, the lights and stereo work and the windows move pretty fast.

In the morning it was still starting fine. When I started driving I felt a slight resistance and then heard a crack sound. The vehicle was driving completely normal so I suspected that I ran over a twig or something similar when starting. I am not sure whether this is related it might also have been a slightly rusted hand break after the heavy rainfalls of the last days.

Any advice what I could try?

I checked all fuses relevant to ignition and ASD according to this guide:
https://fuse-box.info/jeep/jeep-patriot-mk74-2007-2017-fuses-and-relays#2011

The fuses seem fine.

I suspect the starter motor or the relais / electronics associated with it?

Which fuses should I check?
What should be my next steps?

Thanks for your time!